# Created A New MVC Project In VS2015 And Intellisense Produces Error In Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

I just created a new web application (MVC 5.2.3) in Visual Studio 2015, and I regularly get errors like this on the HtmlHelpers:

[image]

I'm using .NET 4.6 (the default project was set to 4.5.2 originally, however I still had this issue with that default setting). I've looked at a bunch of similar questions on this site, and yet I haven't found a solution that consistently works. Any advice?

Comment: Bleep me... I forgot on another question I saw someone who suggested running VS2015 as Administrator. That appears to be doing it for me at this time (I'm 2 for 2 with that solution). If someone wants, they can vote to close this question. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a corrupted MEF cache to me.  Different user, different MEF cache.
The PM of Razor Editing, Mads Kristensen, wrote an extension to make clearing the MEF cache simple. Try this: [Clear MEF Component Cache](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22b94661-70c7-4a93-9ca3-8b6dd45f47cd).
You'll just have to restart VS after clearing; rebuilding the cache takes seconds, not minutes.

Please let us know if this solves the problem for you.

Comment: My application isn't using MEF.

Comment: No, but Visual Studio is, and Razor tooling is loaded via MEF.